# Can I block my Service thread while I call a method on the UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, concurrency

**I have what seems like a stupid requirement:**

I need to block my [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) thread while I run a single method which must be accessed from the UI thread. How can I do this?

Obviously I can run the UI method via a `Handler` with `Looper.getMainLooper()` but of course the rest of my service processing would then continue.

**A bit more detail:**

My Service Sync's content while using binder callbacks to progressively update the UI with the new items. All methods which affect the list of items are UI-Thread bound to avoid my StaggeredGridLayout throwing ConcurrentModificationExceptions.

However, when my service starts I want to call the list to get current id's before I sync each source of content, this is what requires the UI thread access.

The reason I can't just provide this list while starting the Service is that the app must remain responsive (meaning an item can be deleted as we sync), and the list needs to be checked before each additional source of content is synced

**Solutions:**

The best solution I came up with, is to create two Handlers, one on the Main Looper for the UI method, the other for everything else and send messages between them. It doesn't feel like an acceptable, clean solution

The other was to make a threadsafe version of the same UI method, starting by doing an arraycopy of the contents and looping with the copy. I'm not sure if the arraycopy operation is unsafe (prone to ConcurrentModificationException) too, as it's hard to trigger the bug. So I'm not sure this is acceptable either.

Comment: Normally, your service thread *is* the UI thread.

Comment: This is an IntentService, I should have clarified

Comment: wrapping the methods that access the list in a `synchronized` block should do it

Comment: @nandsito do you want to write an answer with an example using a synchronisedList and a synchronised code block?

Comment: giving a better thought, `synchronized` blocks may not be the best approach... in general, `Service`s have a hard time communicating back to an `Activity`, which i believe to be your case. Do you consider doing background work in `AsyncTask`s, plain old `Thread`s or other means?

Comment: This task is too long running for that, and the user can go between several activites during the time it is running. The method I mentioned above is what I went with. If you want to add the answer I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a solution that uses `AsyncTask`.

Here's an `Activity` that calls the task:

```java
public class CallingActivity extends Activity {

    // method that does all the synchronization
    private void doSync() {

        // for each item you want to sync
        int itemId;

        new ItemUpdateAsyncTask(itemId, this).execute();
    }

    // this method is called for each synced item
    public void syncItem(int itemId, Object syncedItem) {
        // update list etc.
    }
}
```

Now, the `AsyncTask` that updates the items in background:

```java
public class ItemUpdateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object> {

    // the id of the item to be updated
    private final int mItemId;
    // reference to the activity that will be notified
    // of the item update
    private final WeakReference<CallingActivity> mCallingActivity;

    public ItemUpdateAsyncTask(int itemId, CallingActivity callingActivity) {
        super();
        mItemId = itemId;
        mCallingActivity = new WeakReference<>(callingActivity);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // sync item in background
        Object syncedItem;

        return syncedItem;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object syncedItem) {
        CallingActivity callingActivity = mCallingActivity.get();
        if (callingActivity != null) {

            // update item in main thread
            callingActivity.syncItem(mItemId, syncedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

I think it is easier to design this solution using `AsyncTask`s instead of `Service`s because of the callback object passing. Services and Activities can only communicate with each other by means of Intents, which can carry only serializable data. As you can see, asynctasks can reference callback objects, which makes things easier. Or else, you would have to register a broadcast receiver in the activity and the service would have to send a broadcast with the updated item, which would need to be serializable. That's a viable solution as well, though.

> the user can go between several activites during the time it is running

It is a point worth noting when you design an architecture like this, that does something in background and pushes the result to the caller. The caller may be e.g. an `Activity` that may be already finished and garbage-collected by the time that the background work finishes. That's the reason I wrapped the caller in a `WeakReference`.

Comment: An intent service has a binder you can use to talk back to your clients you know. My app has an object that that binder talks to, each activity then observes my object (because it's far too long running for an async task). I'll accept this answer as it's the only one and well written